# Yahoo YUI Calendar -- Display Only

Tags: calendar, yui

I'm using the YUI calendar, multi-select, multi-page version. I now need a second page which will display the calendar indicating the selected dates, but will *not* allow the user to click on and select/deselect any of the dates. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the default cell [renderer](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/render.html) method, replacing it with you own renderer. Here's an example of implementing a [read only YUI calender](http://ericmiraglia.com/yui/demos/readonlycalendar.php).